# Dual boot Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have two hard drives, one with Win 10, one with Ubuntu.
I can change the OS by going into Uefi Bios and selecting the disk as the boot drive.
However, I would like a boot menu so I can select after restart. Please help.

Comment: I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Answer (score 1):

If grub menu is not showing up for you when booting from ubuntu drive you can try force it to update as explained in this question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49989/let-grub-re-scan-disks/49998

but a short summary is:
run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and you should be getting os selection when booting linux.

Comment: You have to have both systems in same boot mode, probably UEFI. And Windows fast start up off. Grub only boots working Windows which means fast start up/hibernation must be off and Windows does not need chkdsk.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: good to know, for me generally this always works.    
@Jake B. if update-grub does not work check if bots systems are in same boot mode :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me consistently (update-grub). I have fast start and hibernation off. What happens is: I have disk A (Win) and disk B (Linux). I set disk B as the default boot in bios. Then GRUB menu loads and I can boot to Linux, but not to Windows ("No such device", "File /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmyfw" not found. So I can only boot to Windows if I press F8 and select Win disk in bios to boot from. If I again restart, GRUB shows and I can boot to Win. But if I select Linux again, then restart, next time I cannot boot to Win. Please help, this is furstrating.